# HDMI display detected with "no signal " on Ubuntu 20.04 (Intel Graphics)

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, intel

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop. I have two monitors each connected to a VGA and HDMI port. Both monitors were working fine until a few days ago. Now when I boot, the HDMI monitor doesn't turn on even for showing the BIOS screen, it doesn't display anything despite detecting the laptop's signal and resolution in the Display settings. The monitor keeps saying "no signal" and therefore goes to power-saving mode. I am using a HDMI to VGA adapter which I tested seperately and the display is working fine with other CPUs.

The desktop has no additional graphics card besides the Intel Integrated HD Graphics: UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop).

Here's the xrandr output.

```
~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

```
~$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2726 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (0x46) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 413mm x 234mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  205641
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     HDMI-1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0030ae140a01010101
        2e140104a52917782275a19c54519627
        185054adce0001010101010101010101
        010101010101662156aa51001e30468f
        33009dea1000001e662150b051001b30
        4070360022130000001e000000fd0032
        4b1e3c0e000a202020202020000000fc
        004c454e204431383677410a2020001a
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 86 
        supported: 86
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1366x768 (0x46) 85.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1366 start 1436 end 1579 total 1792 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  774 total  798           clock  59.79Hz
  1360x768 (0x47) 85.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1424 end 1536 total 1792 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  795           clock  60.02Hz
  1024x768 (0x48) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x49) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x4a) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x4b) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x4c) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x4d) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x4e) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x4f) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x50) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x51) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  205641
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP-1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 94 
        supported: 94
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-2 connected 1360x768+1366+0 (0x47) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 406mm x 229mm
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  205641
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6dad4b00000000
        0914010380291778ea2335a4554d9b25
        125054a56a00314f454f614f01010101
        010101010101662150b051001b304070
        360096e51000001e0000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000fd0038
        4b1e3d09000a202020202020000000fc
        0057313934330a2020202020202001e0
        02031b61230907078301000067030c00
        2000802d43908402e2000f8c0ad08a20
        e02d10103e9600a05a00000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000029
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 100 
        supported: 100
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1360x768 (0x47) 85.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1360 start 1424 end 1536 total 1792 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  795           clock  60.02Hz
  1920x1080 (0x52) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x53) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1280x720 (0x54) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x55) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x48) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x4a) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x56) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x4c) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x4d) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x480 (0x57) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x58) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x4e) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x59) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x50) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x51) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
```

Running sudo get-edid | parse-edid produces an error:

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
3 potential busses found: 0 4 5
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
Bus 0 doesn't really have an EDID...
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 4
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "W1943"
    ModelName "W1943"
    VendorName "GSM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 9 of 2010
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 410 230
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-61
    VertRefresh 56-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 90MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 640x480, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 800x600, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1024x768, 75Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
extb[4]: 0x23 (0x20)
Hmm, you have data blocks, but not video ones... weird
Something strange happened. Please contact the author,
Matthew Kern at <pyrophobicman@gmail.com>
```

Although checking both the buses seperately with:

```
sudo get-edid -b 4 | parse-edid
```

, I see the problem is on bus 4. With 5 the edid parses successfully.

I tried checking the display with a Live USB but there also same thing happens, it's detected but with no signal.

Any ideas on how to fix this and if this is a hardware issue or some driver problem. I also tried changing resolutions through the settings for both the displays with no luck.

Edit: I only have one HDMI port but somehow 2 HDMI connections show up in xrandr with one disconnected.

Comment: I've the same exact problem on 20.04, also with an HDMI to VGA adapter. Note that on 19.10 this setup was working correctly. Adding the corret display resolution (mode), which is 1680x1050@60, manually through xrandr works.

Comment: Have tried changing modes through "xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 1024x768 --rate 60". Tried toggling through every mode, still no signal.

Comment: Hi! Same thing here with an HDMI-to-VGA adapter. Did you manage to solve this? Thanks